# Mysql partition columns (Date) execute plan

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance, database-partitioning, database-indexes

That's the structure of the table:

[image]

It's November 30, 2017 in Beijing.
I want to use partition column make it more effective to get my data,You can see the execute plan between two diffrent sqls:

[image]
[image]

I want to make sure that why the execute plans of both are diffrent?
Actually I want to use sql2,but it's two slow.
I'm puzzled by this question.Thanks for answer advance.

Comment: you are missing images. hence your question is not enough explanatory. get ready for down vote from someone unless you correct your question.

Comment: What is the question? You did not ask anything.

Comment: It's my first time to ask question,and it's not convenient to see the pictures..

Comment: I think he cannot insert images with only 1 rep. Consider copying the code into the question (the code is short enough so this should be done).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't put images in your question. Instead, [edit] your question and cut and paste the text of the material you would put in the image. The point of Stack Overflow is to help other people in the future as well as you.

Comment: Thank you all,and now I can see the pitures~

Comment: Where does `id` come from?  It is not `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: For Chinese, you really need utf8mb4, not utf8.

Comment: What `SELECTs` really need partitioning that you cannot get with suitable indexes??  That is, `PARTITIONing` does not magically provide performance; often it degrades performance.

Answer (score 1):

The two queries differ in this way ...

```
 WHERE datecolumn = CONSTANT
```

and

```
 WHERE datecolumn =  DIRTY(GREAT(FUNCTIONAL(expression)))
```

In the second way of doing this, the MySQL query planner can't tell enough about what `datecolumn` values to use to let it pick just one partition to search.

Notice that it probably doesn't make sense to use partitioning to enhance query performance unless

1. You've already done everything you can to use indexes to enhance performance.
2. Your table contains at least 100 million rows.

Partitioning lets you do things like swap out old data fast. But getting it to improve performance is very hard, and limits the kinds of queries you can do. If your labor is worth any money, spend a tenth of that money on some SSD disks instead.

Comment: You get my point! I want to use partition to make query more fast.What I mentioned is just a sample.I make a sql that contains many partitioned tables joined,but i just want to use one of those partitions.How could i make it more fast?

Comment: I use another way that i transform variables to constant. Thank you ~

Comment: What's more,I use now() instead sysdate(), and I reach my purpose~

Comment: Better yet, `CURDATE() - INTRVAL 1 DAY`